# what javascript or css libraries can i use to achieve this dropdown effect?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu

http://www.samsung.com/sg/consumer/pc-peripherals-printer/notebook-pc/smart-pc/XE700T1C-H03SG-dealerlocator

in this webpage, at the left under find a dealer, there is a dropdown for address.

I was wondering if there is any javascript or css library i can use to accomplish the same effect.

Please suggest one which I can modify easily to change:
 the color of the dropdown
 the font type
 the font size 
 the font color

Answer (score 1):

you can use twitter's bootstrap , see here  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/ for document and demo

Comment: you mean http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns in particular?